# predict pulling the wrong data in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, caret

```
library(leaps)
library(caret)
studentreport<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Downloads\\studentreport dataset full imp.csv",header=T,sep=",")
studentreport<-data.frame(studentreport)

set.seed(123)

train_ind<-createDataPartition(studentreport$Enrolling,p=.66,list=FALSE)
training <- studentreport[train_ind, ]
testing <- studentreport[-train_ind, ]

fitreport<-glm(Enrolling~.,train,family="binomial")
Fitstart=glm(Enrolling~1,data=train,family="binomial")

Report<-step(Fitstart,direction="forward",scope=formula(fitreport))
Modelout<-predict(Report,data=test,type="response")

testresults<- ifelse(Modelout> 0.5,TRUE,FALSE)
```

When I look at the str() of each the length of the one gotten by predict comes up as the length of my training data, not my test. Is there a syntax error I am not seeing?

```
> str(testresults)
 Named logi [1:6374] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6374] "1" "4" "5" "6" ...
> str(train$Enrolling)
 logi [1:6374] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
> str(test$Enrolling)
 logi [1:3281] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your statement `Modelout<-predict(Report,data=test,type="response")`

`predict` is looking for an argument called `newdata`, not `data`, so your statement should be:

```
Modelout<-predict(Report, newdata=test, type="response")
```

It may help to look at the help page `?predict.glm`

Comment: I have been looking at the predict help. I didn't know there was a way to do predict.glm. Thanks for the help I am going to try it  now.